# Django order by primary key does not work

Tags: python, django

I have a model as below:

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    path = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Photos"
```

I want to retrieve the last primary key from the database (postgresql) as below:

```
try:
    last_inserted = Photos.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
    print(last_inserted)
except IndexError:
    print("No data in the database")
```

but instead of a primary key I always get a date from the date column which is really strange! printing the last_inserted gives me '2018-09-04'.
As a test I change the 'id' column to lang (does not exists in table) gives below error message:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'lang' into field. Choices are: date, id, name, path, size
```

in the above message why date is coming first then id and so on ..!

please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(last_inserted)` will show you result of model's `__str__` method. To see `id` you can change model:

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    path = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Photos"
```

Or just change query to select only `id` field using [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
last_inserted = Photos.objects.order_by('-id').values_list('id', flat=True)[0]
print(last_inserted)
```

As for

> in the above message why date is coming first then id and so on ..!

I suppose it because of alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it like this. A bit shorter

```
Photos.objects.order_by('-id').first().id
```

There is also a last()